# How to hide menu bar code for login page in phalcon

Tags: phalcon, php, volt

Hi I am developing a website using phalcon. My homepage is divided into header index and footer. The header has a menu bar which is common to all other pages but for the login page I don't want this menu bar. How to hide this menu bar code only in the login page? Please help me.

My menu bar code is

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav main_menu">
        <li><?php echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo(array('index', '<img src="images/home.png">'));?></li>
        <li><?php echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo(array('my-sale', '<img src="images/mysale.png">'));?></li>
        <li><?php echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo(array('customers', '<img src="images/customers.png">'));?></li>
        <li><?php echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo(array('campaign', '<img src="images/campaign.png">'));?></li>
        <li><?php echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo(array('analysis', '<img src="images/analysis.png">'));?></li>
        <li><?php echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo(array('myaccount', '<img src="images/myaccount.png">'));?></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

How to hide this menu bar code in my login page?
Please help.

Comment: Can you please give your login page url?? After take a look hows your loign url may be provide solution.

Comment: its not live yet...its still in the local :-(

Comment: The solution is that you need to check with any specific id or something that if its login page than implement your css class .main_menu{display:none;}

Comment: you said right, like in wordpress we can know the page name or id and can do the if(page) do { this} ,  but in phalcon how to know what page is it.?

Comment: Use this--- if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] !='login.php'){ put menus }

Comment: @SunilPachlangia it did work....yuhuu...thanks mann...

Answer (score 3):

if you use [Hierarchical Rendering](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#hierarchical-rendering) with two main layout then in login action  you can switch to login layout like this:

```
public function loginAction(){
    $this->view->setMainView('login');
}
```